# How to catch inner exception in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have an exception that is triggered by another one.
I have a set of actions meant for that inner exception. Apparently first I have to catch the outmost exception, I do this and then how do I `except` the one that follows?

Comment: Can you show some working example code demonstrating the problem and showing what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: The short answer, if I understand you, is that you can't. But if you explain your motivation and give context, perhaps someone could suggest a better approach.

Comment: @glibdud well actually it's not code-specific, so you can take any such chain of exceptions. I can't do this right now. If it's mandatory then I will do this a tad later.

Comment: It's not about code specificity, it's about illustrating what you're trying to do. I can't tell that from your short description (but it's possible others might).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently first I have to catch the outmost exception

Yes.

> I do this and then how do I except the one that follows

You can not `except` the one that follows because you're too late.  You can examine the context of the exception you did catch, though.  Example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     try:
...         errorerror
...     except NameError:
...         1/0
...         
>>> try:
...     foo()
... except ZeroDivisionError as err:
...     zerr = err
...     
>>> zerr.__context__
NameError("name 'errorerror' is not defined")
```

When cleaning up after the inner exception, there may be other interesting info for you on the outer exception instance.  Look at:

- the `__context__` attribute for implicitly chained exceptions
- the `__cause__` attribute for explicitly chained exceptions
- the `__traceback__` attribute for further context if you need it

See [PEP 3134 -- Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) for further details.

Comment: Seems like the best reply =D Thank you, even though, if you don't mind, I will get back to the question, but a bit later. I will add some more details.